# Returning data from server asp.net mvc action to Jquery Ajax request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I add a link dynamically to a page, and I want the "name" property to be a value that is sent back from server.

This is the code I have for adding a song to the server and then I dynamically  append link to my song with a delete button, and I want that button to have a name equal to the songID evaluated on the server side.

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/AddSong",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#AddTopTenFavForm").serialize(),
            success: function () { ShowMsg("Song Added Successfully"), $(container).find('ul').append('<li><a class="topTenFavLinks" href="#" name="' + substr + '" >' + name + '</a> <span name= @item.SongId class="btnDeleteSong dontDoAnything">x</span></li>'); },
            error: function () { ShowMsg("There was an error therefore song could not be added, please try again") }
        });
```

here is my mvc action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddSong(HomeViewModel songModel)
    {
        var song = new Song();
        song.GenreId = songModel.topTenFav.Rank;
        song.Date = DateTime.Now;
        song.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
        song.Title = songModel.topTenFav.Title;
        song.YoutubeLink = songModel.topTenFav.YoutubeLink;
        repository.AddSong(song);
        repository.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

How would I solve this issue in a single ajax request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return your song ID from the action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSong(HomeViewModel songModel)
{
    //code goes here
    return this.Content(song.Id.ToString());

}
```

and in the javascript `success` callback you will receive data in arguments:

```
success: function (data) { /* use data here for anchor name */ },
```

Comment: in my action I have  return RedirectToAction("Index");
how would I change this to return to index and return json at the sam etime?

Comment: And after Ajax call your page redirects to the Index?

Comment: so the redirect to index in my action is unnecessary if I only call that action method through ajax?

Comment: you can return redirect if it's not ajax call if you needed. But for described scenario you need to return data to the client, not redirect. You can get know if it's ajax request from the `Request.IsAjaxRequest()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use JsonResult to return your Id, and append to your link.

Look at examples

http://shashankshetty.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/using-jsonresult-with-jquery-in-aspnet-mvc/

http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx